Handle Redis values from processing more than once in multi-instance deployment
In .NET API I have a background service that executes every 0.1 seconds, this gets all values from a redis hash key, and runs a for loop with those and then processes those inside the for loop.
The problem is how to handle the multi instance deployment case when the same background service of another instance catches some value that's already being processed by another instance.
Here is some pseudocode:
.NET API Instance 1: 
    CutBackgroundService(Runs every 0.1 seconds): 
        var redisValues = GetRedisValues(hashKey);
        
        foreach value in redisValues: 
            var processedValue = ProcessValue(value);
            UpdateValueInRedis(processedValue);
            
.NET API Instance 2: 
    CutBackgroundService(Runs every 0.1 seconds): 
        // Here we can get the value that's already being processed by instance 1

        var redisValues = GetRedisValues(hashKey);
        
        foreach value in redisValues: 
            var processedValue = ProcessValue(value);
            UpdateValueInRedis(processedValue);

I don't know if it's possible, but if there's a redis lock I might use that. (I'll research it)
Another idea is: Each time a value is retrieved from the Redis key, set a property "Locked" to true, update in redis, and then set "Locked" to false when processing is done.


What are those values behind the redis key? Do they change often? Do any value needs to be processed ones or multiple times depending on time? Knowing more about the nature of those values might help coming up with ideas.

The values behind the redis key are models with ~10 properties. The values need to be processed every N seconds ex: 60 seconds until some condition is met, but while one instance it's processing it, the other instances must NOT.

@Jetonii it looks like you are reinventing a message queue. SO far I know, Redis [because of the obvious reasons] doesn't have this kind of functionality. Even with locking you will find yourself in a situation when one of the background services died and didn't reset the lock or something like that. You could try to distribute those models to different instances by using simple algorithm like "when MODEL_ID % 2 == 0 then first instance processes this model, else second instance picks it up".

@VolodymyrUsarskyy the redis "stream" type is exactly a message queue

@MarcGravell Partially agree. Data streams can't be same as MQ by definition but I was wrong when wrote "Redis doesn't have this kind of functionality" because it has BUT divided into two separate pieces and some part of a typical MQ functionality is missing. Accordingly to the docs (https://redis.io/docs/latest/develop/data-types/streams/) streams always deliver messages to all subscribers (not okay for the author), blocking lists to only one subscriber (looks good). But I don't find info about Redis requeuing removed message when client doesn't confirm that it was processed (like RabbitMQ)

@VolodymyrUsarskyy you're absolutely right that the feature isn't as fully developed as with dedicated products such as RabbitMQ

Locking is an option, but that introduces a lot of complexities of its own. But yes, fields on the hash could hold the current lock expiration (and optionally a separate owner/token), using hsetnx to set a new value exclusively when it does not already exist (concurrency).
The simplest approach is to use atomic operations that either dequeue things or move things between two locations - dequeue if you don't mind what happens if a process dies after taking an item and before processing it, and move if you do (so you have an "in progress" location which you can periodically check for dead items). For example, [b]rpoplpush is a simple queue moving mechanism, but that won't work for a hash - only a list. Since you mention the processing fetches all items: I wonder whether hash is the right storage mechanism.
In redis terms, another option is the stream primitive which allows coordinated consumption of data with multiple behaviour options.
